# How can I add hyperlink in WP_Error message?

Tags: plugins, php, wp-error

I using below code for showing error message to users in my WordPress website

```
if ( $wp_error ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'you_cannot_vote_on_restricted', __( 'Voting on restricted posts are not allowed.', 'anspress-question-answer' ) );
}
```

Now I want show error message to users with hyperlink. I use below code to do that, But this code showing just text

```
    if ( $wp_error ) {
return new WP_Error('no_permission', sprintf(__('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="%s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>'), site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login')));
}
```

[image]

This is my error message

How can I show error message to user with hyperlink?

Comment: How are you displaying the error message?

Comment: I use a plugin, this plugin use WP_Error class for showing message. WP_Error is a class that makes error handling within plugins and WordPress.

Comment: I know what `WP_Error` is, but how that error object is displayed is super important. If that plugin applies escaping to the message on output then your answer is likely a hard no. Either way i cannot determine this as you've neither shared the code or identified the plugin, it isn't even clear where the code your posted is located or how it's called as there's very little context provided